# Move all laravel folders except public inside other directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to move all folders and files inside other folder. 
My structure after moving the files is
1stfolder
-app
--bootstrap
-config
-database
-all other folders and files

2ndfolder
-public_html (which is the folder public)

My problem is when i change

```
require __DIR__.'../../1stfolder/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'../../1stfolder/bootstrap/app.php';
```

it gives me blank page without errors.

This used to work with laravel 5 but it doesnt seem to work with laravel 5.1

Am i doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** After some tests, i think the problem is that laravel doens't find the correct path to the views. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing slashes in your paths, try:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../1stfolder/bootstrap/autoload.php';    
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../1stfolder/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: i get "No such file or directory" in my error_log when i do that. Instead as it is, i don't get any error. Just a blank page.

Comment: Have you switched the order in which files are loaded on purpose? By deault first you should load "autoload.php" and then "app.php"

Comment: The order is as you said, first autoload and then app. I copy-paste it in different order by mistake.

Comment: Could you echo "__DIR__.'/../../1stfolder/bootstrap/autoload.php'"? You should get an absolute path, see if the file exists (ls -alh <path>)

Comment: Ok, so changing the file paths works. Have a look at laravel logs and server logs - you should find error details in there.

Comment: i noticed that pages without any graphical interface with only some echos in them (which i have for testing purposes) work fine, loading rows from database. Any thoughts?

Comment: Error log is clean. Also, I noticed that storage/logs/ is empty as well